# Unable to Fetch Data from Open Weather API in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, flutter-web, openweathermap

My Result

[image]

***Source Code***

**Loading Screen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

  }
  @override
  void getlocation()async{
    Location location=Location();
   await location.getcurrentlocation();
   print(location.lat);
   print(location.long);
  }
  void getdata()async{
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse
      ('samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22')
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      print(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }}
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getlocation();
    getdata();
    return Scaffold(
    );
  }
}
```

**Get CurrentLocation Method**

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
class Location{
  double long;
  double  lat;
  Future<void> getcurrentlocation() async {
    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
      lat = position.latitude;
      long= position.longitude;
    } catch (e) {

    }
  }
}
```

I want **this result**(https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22) but unable to get this. Can you please tell me where I am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the `https://` to your url.
like this:

```
Uri.parse('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22');
```

Also, please always post your code in text, not images.

Comment: The https:// doesn't work. It's showing the error "XML Http Request error"

Comment: Are you running this on Flutter web?

Comment: Yes i am running this on Web

Comment: You needed to mention this in your post, this is related to CORS, as the API doesn't allow cross content origin content,. You problem to start with is solved, by adding the https to your Uri. The second problem is different. 
I doubt you are currently using any .htacces files or running a mock server.

Disabling CORS policy on Chrome is a temporary solution. If you run it on a phone, it'll work. Read more about CORS and the new error. 
If this has helped you kindly mark it as an answer. Happy coding.

Comment: Thankyou sooooooo much

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach

```
var url = Uri.https('samples.openweathermap.org', 'data/2.5/weather', {
  'lat': '35',
  'lon': '139',
  'appid': 'b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22'
});

http.Response weatherResponse = await http.get(url);
```